# Configure IIS to use different robot.txt for https requests

Tags: iis, iis-7, robots.txt

How do I use a different robots.txt for https request than the one that is used for http connections in IIS 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options here, depending on how custom you need this to be.  Most flexible approach would be to write a handler and map to it for robots request, and handle internally.

However, for most needs, try to URL rewrite module
http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

off top of my head (aka prob doesnt work 100%), its something like :

```
<rule name="https_robots">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/robots-https.txt" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Use Url Rewrite to rewrite https://www.whatever.com/robots.txt to https://www.whatever.com/robots-for-https.txt or whatever you  need.  Gave ya an example, see editted answer

Comment: Indeed with URL Rewrite you should be able to add a rule like Taylor suggests that can return a different file (through a Redirect, or maybe it could be easier to just do a rewrite to a different file like robotsSSL.txt), in that file set a Disallow:/ so that it blocks all.

Answer (score 0):

Got exactly the same problem:

I am setting up https version now, want to look at it and debug it without a rush, meanwhile fending off Google from crawling https, but keeping http "business as usual". Here's the piece of code I used in a config file:

```
<rule name="https_robots"  stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^robots\.txt$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="robots_https.txt" />
</rule>
```

A few notes:

Basically, I've created a file "robots_https.txt" containing "disallow for all" instruction.

I used Rewrite, not Redirect. I am not sure if the spider would get the redirect. I really doubt that. With Rewrite you can't go wrong.

Hope that helps!